# Spring Cloud: Call Eureka-enabled service with Ribbon without @EnableEurekaClient?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

Is there a way to call an Eureka-enabled service without needing to the calling consumer to register itself with Eureka? Or in other words without having @EnableEurekaClient annotation? Or in yet more other words, is there a way to call Eureka-enabled service using Ribbon load-balancer from a non-Spring Java app?

I wasn't able to get it from the documentation. Are there any examples of this?

Answer (score 0):

You can set `eureka.client.registerWithEureka: false`. You can certainly use ribbon and eureka in java without spring, refer to their documentation.